# Sorting Scripture References

Tags: sorting

I'm working on a CSCI Capstone focusing on Text-Searching through the Bible and, because of the nature of my program, am returning an unordered list of scripture references formatted as such:  "nameOfBook chapNum: verseNum".

After I get the list of references, I need to sort them on all three fields:  name, chapter, and verse, in that order, and I'm hoping to avoid using an O(n^3) algorithm.  I already have code that sorts each reference on the book name, which was O(n), but I don't really know where to go from here...

Suggestions?

Edit:  I'm working in Java with Arrays and am looking at storing the sorted data into a text file that can be accessed later on.

Comment: What programming language do you want to use?  Will you be storing the data in a database, writing text files, or just displaying it?

Comment: You need to explain your question further. As it stands, this isn't helpful.

Comment: I'm working in Java with arrays.  The scripture references are being stored as Strings and will, eventually, be saved into a text file that will be used as a reference later on

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to have a single sort by name, chapter, and verse, then you can either set up a sort that uses all three of those things together as a key for sorting, or you can use a "stable sort" and sort by verse, then by chapter, then by name.

Here's pseudocode in Python.  It's real Python code except I don't have definitions for `parse_code()`, `get_name()`, `get_chapter()`, or `get_verse()`.

```
lst = []
for x in parse_code(input_file):
    name = get_name(x)
    chapter = get_chapter(x)
    verse = get_verse(x)
    tup = (name, chapter, verse)
    lst.append(tup)

lst.sort()  # will automatically do what you want
```

When you have a list made up of tuples, and you sort the list, Python will sort based on the first item in the tuple, followed by the second, followed by the third.

On the other hand, if you are trying to build three different indexes, maybe the simplest implementation would be to stash the data in a database, and put an index on each of name, chapter, and verse.  You could use SQLite for the database; for a project the size of the text in the Bible I think it would work well.

Comment: To use this code for sorting the books canonically, not alphabetically, you'll to specify the `key` argument to the `sort` method. [This page](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/sorting.html#the-old-way-using-the-cmp-parameter) should be helpful in getting the details right.

Comment: Yes, when I said it will "do what you want" I was assuming an alphabetic sort.

Comment: I'm looking for Biblical order, so sorting canonically, as chepner suggested above

Comment: Okay, makes sense.  That's easy to do in Python with a `key` argument, but since you said you are using Java there isn't much point in a code example in Python.